# "The controller must return a response" while using @Template annotation

Tags: symfony, annotations, twig

Using Symfony Framework:

`"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1"`
+
`"symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.1"`
with default configuration.

Receive error: `The controller must return a response (Array() given).`

Sample code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("", name="index")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I tried to add:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
   view:
      annotations: true
```

But it doesn't work

I have same sample project with `"symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0"` and it work properly.

Comment: Is the framework extra bundle in config/bundles.php?

Comment: Yes, it is in bundles.php

Comment: Run "bin/console debug:event-dispatcher" and verify you have  kernel.view TemplateListener::onKernelView

Comment: `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher |grep TemplateListener -c`
`0`

Comment: no `TemplateListener::onKernelView` in output

Comment: That explains the error message.  I don't know if the templating component talked about in the question is really relevant.  You would have needed to take some extra steps to install and enable the templating component.  I just did a fresh 4.1 website-skeleton install and it all seems to work as expected.  Maybe you can start over?

Comment: Oops.  I meant the templating component talked about in the answer.  I suppose you could double check that config/packages/framework.yaml has no templating section.  Which it won't unless you put it in there.

Comment: I tried to start over, and use fresh 4.1 website-skeleton and get this error again ;(

Comment: @Cerad I not have templating section in framework.yaml ;/

Comment: Interesting.  All you did was a simple "composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton" and nothing else?  php version?  Not sure what to tell you.

Comment: Only `composer create-project symfony/skeleton .` or `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton .` + `composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev` + `composer require annotations`. PHP 7.2.4

Comment: Well, you got me.  Be sure to come back if you figure it out.  Maybe "composer self-update"?

Comment: lol, `composer require twig-bundle` solve problem.

Comment: Well yeah.  You do need need twig installed to use a twig template.  That is why I suggested using the website-skeleton to create your project.  It has all the obvious dependencies (including twig and annotations).  But glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I created a new project from scratch, but did not use the `symfony/website-skeleton` package that would normally install all dependencies.  So it wasn't just that my `@Template` annotation wasn't working, it was that no templates were working because Twig wasn't installed.

I ran the command `composer require twig-bundle` and it solved the problem.

Comment: that was apparently my issue as well! I'm surprised the error message given by Symfony is so vague! there was no indication to me that a lack of Twig was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [@Template annotation documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html).  It states:

> As of version 4.0 of the bundle, only Twig is supported by the @Template annotation (and only when **not** used with the Symfony Templating component -- no `templating` entry set in the `framework` configuration settings).

I imagine you are using the Symfony Templating component in which case this will not work.  Or, you may also have your template file named improperly - it should be named after the controller and action name.

Better still, have a look at [Symfony's Best Practices for Templates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html) which recommends that you store templates in the `templates/` directory of your root project, rather than a bundle's `Resources/views/` folder.  This means that you no longer reference templates like `@App/Index/Index.html` or use the magic `@Template` annotation.  You would instead explicitly call your template from your controller like so:

```
/**
 * @Route("", name="index")
 */
public function index()
{
    return $this->render('index/index.html.twig');
}
```

Finally, and this may seem obvious, but make sure you have Twig installed in your project (`composer require symfony/twig-bundle`).

Comment: Path for my template `templates/index/index.html.twig`

Comment: How to disable "Symfony Templating component"?

Comment: You probably don't have it enabled by default, just look in your composer.json for `symfony/templating`. If it's there it is installed/enabled. Also try `@Route("/", name="index") as it might need that.  And again w/best practices I'd probably call the `render` function explicitly.

Comment: Yes, `symfony/templating` not in my composer.json

Comment: `@Route("/", name="index")` not change situation :(

Comment: I use `@Tamplate()` in all my projects and it works. Previous project was created with `"symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0"` and same code with template annotation work properly.

Comment: You'll want to remove the symfony/templating then and also remove it from your framework configuration